# Additive group contains exactly three elements of the set $\{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. There is a proper subgroup $J$ of the additive group of integers which contains exactly three elements of the set $\{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}$. Which three elements are in $J$?

I know the solution is $\{p,pq,p^q\}$. However I do not understand why. I thought $J$ can not even be a finite group. Maybe there is serious misunderstanding of the problem. Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, $J$ is not finite. But it will only contain $3$ of the elements in the given set. The reason it must be those is that if it contained any other $3$, it would contain at least one more of them.

Comment: Would you please explain a little bit more? For example, let $p=3$ and $q=5$, the set becomes $\{3,15,243\}$. How can this be a group? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I said, it is not a subgroup. $J$ is not the set of those three elements. Rather, it turns out that $J$ is the set of all multiples of $p$. But the only elements in $J$ that are also in the given set are those three.

Comment: The statement "$J$ contains exactly three elements of the set $\{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}$" does not mean that $J$ is a three-element subset of $\{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}$. Rather, it means that $J\cap\{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}$ is a three-element set. In your example with $p=3$ and $q=5$, $J=\{\dots,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you let $x,y\in J$ with $(x,y)=1$, then $J=\mathbb Z$. You can use the Euclidean algorithm to find $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ so that $mx+ny=1$, hence $\langle 1 \rangle\subset J\implies J=\mathbb Z$.